# how to open the html form as pop up using fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent html page where in I have button to open the dialog box(child page - form) and take the inputs from dialog box and come back to parent page and use the values.

HTML button:

```
<div class="fancybox">
<input type="button" id="opener" value="X" name="1"></td>
</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

The div tag that I am trying to open as dialog:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
Weight<input type="text" id="wt" name="weight"  title="Weight"/>
Length<input type="text" id="lgt" name="length"  title="Length"/>
Width<input type="text" id="wdt" name="width"  title="Width"/> 
Height<input type="text" id="ht" name="height"  title="Height"/>
<ul id="categories">
  <li id="cat-1">
  <img src="Images/download.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
onclick="PopulateDetails(1,1,1,1)">
  </li>
  <li id="cat-2">
   <img src="Images/Fedex_express.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
onclick="PopulateDetails(2,2,2,2)">
  </li>
  <li id="cat-3">
   <img src="Images/download.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
onclick="PopulateDetails(3,3,3,3)">
  </li>
  <li id="cat-4">
   <img src="Images/Fedex_express.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
onclick="PopulateDetails(4,4,4,4)">
  </li>
</ul>
<button name="OK" onclick="PopulateForm()">OK</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<input type="button" href="#dialog" id="opener" value="X" name="1"></td>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#opener").fancybox();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VWsRP/179/)

Comment: Thanks its working, but I want to send the values from the dialog to html back. Also When I press OK button in the form, the dialog is not closing.

Comment: @Praveen You have to write submit function for that form in that you have to close that fancybox manually like this `$.fancybox.close()`

Comment: Thanks alot Sridhar, now I have one more req, I have more than one button generated in Javascript. Earlier in Jquery I use to catch the value of row(passed in name attribute) whichever button is pressed as in: pkg = $('this').attr('name'); do we have anything in fancybox to do the same.